# Duplicate Wordpress wysiwyg images appear on single page template

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, advanced-custom-fields

I have a very unusual Wordpress Issue.

I am using the ACF repeater field plugin on my site. My issue is when I add images to the wysiwyg editor with the upload media button it appears multiple time on the page, once in the correct place inside the text but two duplicates appear above the navigation bar.

Totally baffled by this issue. I dont think it has anything to with my code. If I remove the section that outputs the content from the wysiwyg it is still there.

Cheers for any help

Comment: Without seeing anything, hard to help. Anyway, the [ACF Wordpress wysiwyg](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/wordpress-wysiwyg/) states that _it does not work within a repeater field when adding a new row_. Something related to that ?

Comment: Yeah I understand that man, unfortunately I cant upload any images here. The actual wysiwyg works fine, the text and image appear fine in the area that they are outputted . Its only when an image is inserted into the wysiwyg two copies of the same image appear directly after the closing body tag which makes no sense to me.

Read that article and you could very well be right.  May just need to remove the upload media option, cheers for your help man.